# How to create a private network for 2 VMs across different VM host?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have 2 VMs running on separate Hyper-V hosts. I want to create a private network so that the 2 VMs can talk to each other but they cannot access the external network.

I know VLAN would be one option. But my switch doesn't support VLAN.

Can I find some software which acts as a network bridge to connect these VMs?

Comment: Virtual Private Network

Comment: Or just plug a connection directly between spare interfaces on the hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to create a seperate vlan for these vm's even without managed switches - although whether it actually works depends on your particular switch.

The reason you really need a managed switch with vlans is when you want to for example have one port with multiple vlans (trunk port), then use the switch to split this so some ports have one vlan and other ports have another vlan (access ports).

In your scenario, everything else will be untagged, and hopefully your switches should still forward tagged packets, but the only devices on your network that will interact with this vlan will be devices you have set to be on this vlan.

Here is someone explaining it in a little more detail http://blog.pressure.net.nz/2008/11/the-amazing-unmanaged-trunk-mode-switch/

Here is someone explaining why it may possibly not work (read the 4th reply) http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/119788-will-vlan-tags-pass-through-a-basic-simple-switch

Edit: or do as others have mentioned and have a dedicated nic at each end and a crossover cable.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the Hyper-V hosts using a crossover cable. Setup a new Virtual Switch with a new Virtual Network using the Crossover NIC on each Hyper-V and set the network type to external.  Configure each VM to use the new NIC network.  You should be able to use a standard cable if your NICs support auto-MDIX.